# Finding the closure of the following topology

Tags: general-topology

A = (0, 1] as a subset of the space Y = (0, 3] with the standard topology

I found that the interior of A = (0,1), but I am having trouble figuring out the closure of A. My first guess was (0,1], but I don't think (1,3] is open. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(0,1]$ is closed in $Y=(0,3]$ as $[0,1]$ is closed in $\Bbb R$ and $[0,1] \cap Y = (0,1]$.

Or alternatively, its complement within $Y$ is $(1,3] = (1,4) \cap Y$, which is open in $Y$.

Answer (score 0):

Your guess is right.   $(0,1]$ is closed in $(0,3]$.

Comment: Can you explain why? Why is (1,3] open in Y?

Comment: You need the closure to be closed.

Comment: I know. But why is (0,1] closed? That is what I do not understand

Comment: I didn't mean you were right about it being open:   it isn't.

Comment: It contains all of its limit points,  as one way to see it.

Comment: Sorry.  $(1,3]$ is open.  Remember $Y$ is both open and closed in itself.

Comment: I thought a subset is closed iff the entire set - subset is open. Is this wrong?

Comment: Yeah.  I didn't follow what you were doing for a sec.

Comment: It's correct, the complement is open.

Comment: Note:  being open in $Y$ is different than being open in $\Bbb R$.  Open sets in $Y$ are intersections of open sets in $\Bbb R$ with $Y$.

Comment: I see. So for example, (1,3] is open in Y since it is the intersection of (1,4) which is open in R and Y???

Comment: Yes.  In other words,  the standard topology on $Y$ is the _subspace topology_.   For $Y$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R$.